# 'variable' : function(req, res){} means?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I am currently starting with node.js, so I am for the first time using Js beyond dom manipulation.

I came across a code piece like below. I cant understand it. What is happening? is it a key value object? Is an anonymous `function` being passed to `'new'`?

```
module.exports = {

  'new': function(req, res) {
    res.view();
  },

  /**
   * Overrides for the settings in `config/controllers.js`
   * (specific to UserController)
   */
  _config: {}


};
```

Comment: It means that `module.exports.new` will be a function that takes two arguments and calls the `view` method on the second argument.

Comment: I hope this doesn't sound rude, but you should really take a little time to learn JavaScript. Object literals are extremely basic stuff, and it's likely you'll have a lot of trouble if you don't have a good grasp on the basics.

Comment: @chuk: I take it positively. I definetely have to look at JS one more time in a more deeper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like basic JavaScript.

An object named *module* has a property named *exports* that is an object.

This object has a property named *new* whose value is an anonymous function.

In theory you could invoke the method like this:

```
module.exports.new(someRequest, someResponse);
```

Comment: IE8 doesn't allow `module.exports.new`. It wants `module.exports['new']`

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this is ultimately just creating an object called `module.exports` then assigning two properties to it. One is another object called `_config` and the other is a function called `new` that expects two arguments.

That's the plain JavaScript explanation.

In node.js, you're also seeing a few conventions in play, which I'll describe below.

---

One convention is `module.exports`.

This is the object that will be made available when some other code loads this file using `require()`. It would work something like this:

```
var m = require('yourmodule.js');
m.new(req, res);
```

---

Another convention is the pair of arguments: `req, res`.

These are usually parameters that represent a request (like an `http.IncomingMessage`) and a response (like a `http.ServerResponse`).

---

Putting it all together, this module is probably defining a Controller that will receive http requests, and render them as responses. It currently does this for `new`, and there are probably routes configured elsewhere that call this method when a user requests something like 'http://server.come/user/new'.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My doubt was exactly about the line I pasted in the title. Got it cleared below. I really appreciate the answer. Upvoting.